# No permissions in AndroidManifest.xml and app still works

Tags: android-manifest, android-permissions, user-permissions

The app has declared following permissions

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> <!-- Universal image loader -->
<!-- Parse -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> <!-- ConnectivityManager -->
<!-- Parse -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/> <!-- UUID generation -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> <!-- Universal image loader -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/> <!-- Parse -->
<!-- <uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY" /> -->

<permission
    android:name="com.stylectapp.stylect.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.stylectapp.stylect.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
```

I want to debug what's necessary by removing all permissions and see where the app crashes. However, I see that app crashes only on Android 4 and only, because of

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
```

I'm confused that app works without any permissions, because e.g. I download things over network

Do you have an idea, what's wrong?